# How do I merge into an existing unique id in MongoDB with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to sum a documents field when I insert a new entry that has a duplicate unique id. This is what I have so far:

```js
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const dbo = db.db("mydb");
            const messageTable = dbo.collection("comments");
            for(var key in words){
                let myobj = 
                [{ 
                    _id: key,
                    frequency: words[key]
                }];
                messageTable.insertMany(myobj, function(err, res){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("documents inserted");
                });
                messageTable.aggregate([
                    { $match: { _id: key } },
                    {
                      $group: {
                        _id: key, 
                        total: {
                          $sum: "$frequency"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    { $merge: { into: "comments", whenMatched: "replace" } }
                ]);
            }
        })
```

From reading the docs I tried to use the aggregate method to merge new entries if the key already exists as a unique id. This is not currently working. How would I merge duplicate documents in my MongoDB using NodeJS?

Comment: Can you edit this question with input/ sample existing docs & required o/p ?

Comment: @whoami I am sorry I am very much a beginner and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Hi @TDonnally. Just to clarify a few things; Why are you using `insertMany` instead of `insert` since you are inserting just one object? Also, the aggregation you have up there, it is simply to avoid duplicate comments with the same _id right?

Comment: Yes the aggregation is to avoid storing comments in my database twice. I used InsertMany because InsertOne was not working at the time.

Comment: I was going to suggest the answer you posted. Nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this by reading the docs and with the help of a reddit user. If anyone wants to do something similar this is the easiest method:

```js
messageTable.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : key },{$set: { "_id" : key}, $inc : { "frequency" : words[key] }},{upsert: true}).then(
                    console.log("document updated or inserted")
                )
```

With this method the first argument is your query, the second changes the first match which in my case increments the frequency field, and the third are options for the method. The upsert option  has a default value of false but when true creates a new document if one does not already exist. If you wish to read more you can find info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#update-document-with-upsert)